# MongoDB logrotate config

Tags: linux, mongodb, logging, logrotate

I am using MongoDB 1.6.4. The script I used is:

```
/usr/local/test/r0/log/mongo.log {
    daily
    rotate 10
    nocompress
    dateext
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /export/home/d01/test/data/v1/mongo/repl0/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

and the result is like that:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 12 04:02 mongo.log.2015-05-11T20-02-03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1999708 May 12 04:02 mongo.log-20150512
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 13 04:02 mongo.log.2015-05-12T20-02-02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3127517 May 13 04:02 mongo.log-20150513
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    875125 May 13 10:46 mongo.log
```

I do not know why there is a dummy log. Is there mistake on my script? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out the problem is related to postrotate. I changed to the following script and it works fine.

```
/bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MongoDB is using a build-in logrotate option.
The the empty files are created by mongodb.

You can try to turn off the option in mongodb with the command
    `{ logRotate: 0 }`

Or, leave it on and disable your system's logrotate for MongoDB.

Comment: I thought you are correct but I tried to set { logRotate: 0 } and the dummy logs were still generated in these few days.